# opencv tutorial problem with samples::findFile()

Tags: c++, opencv

when I'm trying to run [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html) tutorial
I'm getting this problem on samples::findFile()
I tried to `#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>`
but same problem, any idea?
I'm getting this errors:
[image]

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
// we're NOT "using namespace std;" here, to avoid collisions between the beta variable and std::beta in c++17
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main(void)
{
    double alpha = 0.5; double beta; double input;
    Mat src1, src2, dst;
    cout << " Simple Linear Blender " << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "* Enter alpha [0.0-1.0]: ";
    cin >> input;
    // We use the alpha provided by the user if it is between 0 and 1
    if (input >= 0 && input <= 1)
    {
        alpha = input;
    }
    src1 = imread(samples::findFile("LinuxLogo.jpg"));
    src2 = imread(samples::findFile("WindowsLogo.jpg"));
    if (src1.empty()) { cout << "Error loading src1" << endl; return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    if (src2.empty()) { cout << "Error loading src2" << endl; return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    beta = (1.0 - alpha);
    addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0, dst);
    imshow("Linear Blend", dst);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. You should include your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I installed OpenCV using [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) tutorials (pre-build version) 
and when I tried to go over the introduction I got errors on the "blending two images" tutorial, specific with the `samples::findFile()`
The problem was fixed by changing the version from 3.5.3 to 4.5.3. don't forget to change the property part too, according to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html) steps

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.